# How should I define Pom.xml in each Module so that web module can communicate with the other two ejb modules?

Tags: java, maven, build

Maven, maven, maven. It must be very nice and it is nice by a small application.

Now I want to build an ear project: with two EJB Modules, a web Module and ear module to build an ear file.
Web Module is dependent on the other ejb modules..

How should I define Pom.xml in each Module so that web module can communicate with the other two ejb modules in ear and the ear module builds the right ear file?

What I have done before:

Module 1  --> Basic Module. All other modules are dependent to this Module. Basic functionality like login etc.

```
<packaging>ejb</packaging>
```

Module 1 --> Data Module. All Entites are here Type EJB

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myCompnay</groupId>
    <artifactId>Modul_Basic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>ejb</type>
</dependency
```

Module 2 --> Business Module. Businnes Facades are here. Type EJB

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myCompnay</groupId>
    <artifactId>Modul_Basic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>ejb</type>
</dependency
```

Web Module -> Type is WAR

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.myCompnay</groupId>
        <artifactId>Modul_Basic</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency
```

EAR Module --> In this project I try to build the project.

```
<packaging>ear</packaging>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myCompnay</groupId>
        <artifactId>Modul_Basic</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency
            <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myCompnay</groupId>
        <artifactId>Modul_Business</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myCompnay</groupId>
        <artifactId>Modul_WEB</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>               
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen see what i have done before :-)

Comment: And what does the maven build do incorrectly compared to what you want?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Die EJB Modules are packed into WEB War und Ear. It exists two times.(In War und in Ear) And The Application Server does not find the classes from the Module data

Answer (score 1):

You should have a separate jar module with *just* your ejb interfaces and related interface objects (i.e. your ejb API).  (btw, this issue is unrelated to maven, you would have the same problem using any build system).  your current setup has 4 modules (2 ejb, 1 war, 1 ear).  instead, you should have 5 modules:

- EJB API (jar): just ejb interfaces and possible data objects used in those interfaces
- EJB A,B (ejb): the ejb implementations, depends on the API jar
- WEB (war): depends on the API jar, *not* the ejb jars
- EAR (ear): depends on ejbs and war.

this is a typical client/server setup.  your server will generally consist of a "public API" module and an "implementation" module.  the "public API" would be distributed to any client implementations.

UPDATE:

i may have misunderstood your problem (it's also been a while since i've done Java EE stuff).  I think you may just need to mark the "basic" dependency in your war module as scope "provided", e.g.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myCompnay</groupId>
    <artifactId>Modul_Basic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>ejb</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This will allow you to compile against the classes, but the ejb jar will not be included in the war.  i *believe* that the ejb jars will be available from the war classloader.

Comment: Can you explain a little what you said??

Comment: @Kayser - added a bit more.  is there something specific which is missing/confusing?

Comment: I have an JSF project. Managed Beans are in WEB Module. They call Business Facade in business module.(via Injection). And the managed beans use entities as detached. The type of both is currently ejb. Should the type of module data be "jar "??

Comment: I tried it. But maven ignores the provided tag when the type is ejb. :-(